# Username and password not accepting in jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, dsl, zap

I am trying to create a jenkins CI pipeline and my code is written using jenkins DSL.Specifically,I am facing issue when  am passing username and password to dsl api for ZAP(zad attack proxy) by parameterized Build.The error getting displayed is:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method call() on null object

I believe this means that am passing a null object which is not accepted,but i verified that there was no empty data i was passing to the DSL.

When i am creating a job with ZAP config using DSL API referrence,it works fine.
Not sure where is the issue.Hope somebody can help in this issue.Pls let me know if more details are needed on the above issue.

Comment: Please, could you post some of your code?

Comment: GrafiCode Studio,The code is commercial,but the Jenkins DSL code for zap(Execute ZAP) is used from the Jenkins DSL api doc.I am passing parameters in Json form which has username and password ,to the Jenkins job but the Build fails with above mentioned error.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally fixed the above error.The error occurred due to multiple times declaration of same variable.So Simple error.

Comment: Thanks for following up